# Not able to get name attribute using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

this is how i am declaring Number Spinnner elements in my jsp page

```
<table width="40%">
    <tr>
        <td class="proplabel"><label for="tTestDuration">Test Duration</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestDuration" value="60" data-dojo-    props="smallDelta:1,     constraints:{min:1,max:600,places:0},required:true" name="testDuration" />(Seconds)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="proplabel"><label for="tTestMinFrameRate">Minimum Frame Rate</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestMinFrameRate" value="1" data-dojo-    props="smallDelta:1,     constraints:{min:1,max:10000,places:0},required:true" name="initialRate" />(Mbps)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="proplabel"><label for="tTestMaxFrameRate">Maximum Frame Rate</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestMaxFrameRate" value="100" data-dojo-    props="smallDelta:1,     constraints:{min:1,max:10000,places:0},required:true" name="maximumRate"/>(Mbps)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="proplabel"><label for="tTestStepSize">Step Size</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestStepSize" value="5" data-dojo-    props="smallDelta:1,     constraints:{min:1,max:100,places:0},required:true" name="stepRate" />(Mbps)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="proplabel"><label for="tTestAcceptableLoss">Acceptable Loss</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestAcceptableLoss" value="0" data-dojo-    props='smallDelta:1,     constraints:{min:0,max:10,places:0},required:true' name="acceptableLoss" />(%)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my script, I am using dojo.query to get the nodeList and then the node name and value.
Using these node name and value , constructing an object to send to server.

My Question is I am **not able to get the node name**, name is coming as empty, I checked using console.log() and alert()  but **able to get the node id and node value**

Here is the script I used to query

Tried with **domAttr, dojo.attr** ...nothing worked for me
please tell me how to get the name attribute
even the simple one `**document.getElementById(node.id).name**` did not work

FYI:

I am using dojo version 1.8.4

```
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/form/CheckBox",
        "dijit/form/NumberSpinner",
        "dijit/form/Form",          
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/query",
        "dojo/dom-attr",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(parser,domAttr){
        parser.parse();
    });
</script>
<script>
function myOnClick(jsonObj){
      if(document.getElementById("tt").checked){
            var tt = new Object();
            tt['name'] = "Throughput_"+jsonObj['profileName'];
            tt['frameSize'] = frameSize;
            require(["dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom"], function(domAttr, dom){
                dojo.query('input[id^="tTest"]').forEach(function(node, index, arr){
                    alert(" ----"+node.id+" --"+dojo.byId(node.id).name);

                    tt[domAttr.getNodeProp(node.id,"name")] = node.value;

                  });
            });
            alert(JSON.stringify(tt));
            jsonObj['throughputTest'] = tt; 
        }
}
</script>
```

thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that, the moment you work with Dijits like `dijit/form/NumberSpinner`, your HTML markup gets processed and converted to something else (= the widget).

What happens is that your `dijit/form/NumberSpinner`, once parsed, puts the name attribute on a hidden field and the ID attribute on another field, meaning they're no longer available on the same element.
When working with widgets, you should no longer rely on the HTML markup.

What you could do however, is to obtain the widget using the `dijit/registry` module and work with that. For example, the following will work:

```
registry.byId("tTestDuration").name; // Returns "testDuration"
```

To obtain all names of the widgets inside the table, you could use the `dijit/registry::findWidgets()` method, for example:

```
var widgets = registry.findWidgets(query("table")[0]); // Find widgets inside the table
var names = array.map(widgets, function(widget) {
    return widget.name; 
});
```

This will retrieve all the widget objects first, and then I'm mapping those onto a new array containing only the names of the widgets.

Take a look at the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6EQ75/